# Getting <parsley:ContextBuilder from popup window

Tags: apache-flex, parsley

I'm using

`<parsley:ContextBuilder config="{Parsley_Config}"/>`

in my main application. The problem is popup window cannot detect the configuration. Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section about it in the Parsley documentation :

http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/view.php#popup

Answer (score 0):

help for this topic - how to handle popup and windows using parsley
http://flexfinds.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/parsley-and-popups.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.